# Count occurrences of each value on specific meta value

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a wp_query to retrieve all post type with specific meta_key/meta_value and I can't change it because this query is used in other 5 loops in same page.

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'item',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',

    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'basicYear',
            'value'     => '1888',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    )
));
```

I have this loop to only show the information of specific field;

```
while( $posts->have_posts() ){ 
        $posts->the_post();
        the_field('relBrand', get_field('basicBrandName'));  
    }
```

I need to count occurrences of the the_field('relBrand', get_field('basicBrandName'));

Ex: Brand A (1), Brand B (6), Brand D (2);

Does anyone knows how to do it without change the wp_query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define array at the top and then just update counts
$brandCounters = array();

In loop change
the_field('relBrand', get_field('basicBrandName')); 
to

```
$brand = get_field('relBrand', get_field('basicBrandName'));
echo $brand;
if(!empty($brandCounters[$brand])) {
    $brandCounters[$brand] = $brandCounters[$brand]++;
}else{
    $brandCounters[$brand] = 1;
}
```

Better move this code to functions;

Comment: Perfect Andrey.

Thank you so much, It's only necessary to change ++ to +1 to increase the value.

to prente the value I used

foreach($brandCounters as $brand => $value){
   echo $brand ." ". $value ."<br />";
  }

Comment: Glad to help ))